# validate multiple strings in Angular

Tags: angular, validation

I want validate some strings in a input type text, if the string is blue, red or green, the validation is correct, else incorrect. How can I validate? I've tried this but only works for the first color.

```
colorValidator():ValidatorFn {

    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null =>

        control.value === ( 'blue' || 'red' || 'green') ? null : {correctColor: control.value};

  }
```

I have seen that the code works to test a string and I thought it would serve to validate several, but it doesn't work, I don't know how to do it.

This is the html form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <h4 class="error">{{message}}</h4>
   <form (ngSubmit)="createWine()" [formGroup]="wineForm">
    <div>
      <div>
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Wine Name" formControlName="name">
      </div>
      <div class="error" *ngIf="(name.dirty || message) && name.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="name.errors['required']"> Insert color </div>
        <div *ngIf="name.errors['correctColor']">The color isn't valid
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a regex out of those colors and use `Validators.pattern(/blue|red|green/)`

```
color: new FormControl('', {
  validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\b(blue|red|green)\b(?!\s)/),
}),
```

like this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zs3oxj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

or if you want exact match:
use \b as word boundary:
`Validators.pattern(/\b(blue|red|green)\b/)`

---

A custom validation function instead of Regex patterns:

```
const colorValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  const color = control.value;
  const validColors = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];
  if (validColors.some((validColor) => validColor === color)) return null;

  return {
    correctColor: 'Enter valid color',
  };
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cqnjsu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Seems good but don't works, I can insert antoher string and don't alert me, if someone write antoher different word than blue, red or green, it have to get the message "the color is not valid". And the idea is create a custom function to validation. But thanks.

Comment: In that case you want a word boundary and to make sure it's not followed by a space. 
Here is the regex validator for that:

```Validators.pattern(/\b(blue|red|green)\b(?!\s)/)```

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e3j3sc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: ok this one that works well with the Regex. Is there a way to create a function and call it after Validators.required? Example: [Validators.required, nameFunction ()]. I've tried the custom validation function but Visual Studio says that I need a parameter when I call the function.

Comment: yes it is the 2nd part of my answer. I also provided a stackblitz link to that one